# Order in Limited query with composite keys on cassandra

Tags: cassandra, time-series, composite-key, composite-primary-key, in-clause

In the following scenario:

```
CREATE TABLE temperature_by_day (
   weatherstation_id text,
   date text,
   event_time timestamp,
   temperature text,
   PRIMARY KEY ((weatherstation_id,date),event_time)
)WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (event_time DESC);

INSERT INTO temperature_by_day(weatherstation_id,date,event_time,temperature)
VALUES ('1234ABCD','2013-04-03','2013-04-03 07:01:00','72F');

INSERT INTO temperature_by_day(weatherstation_id,date,event_time,temperature)
VALUES ('1234ABCD','2013-04-03','2013-04-03 08:01:00','74F');

INSERT INTO temperature_by_day(weatherstation_id,date,event_time,temperature)
VALUES ('1234ABCD','2013-04-04','2013-04-04 07:01:00','73F');

INSERT INTO temperature_by_day(weatherstation_id,date,event_time,temperature)
VALUES ('1234ABCD','2013-04-04','2013-04-04 08:01:00','76F');
```

If I do the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM temperature_by_day
WHERE weatherstation_id='1234ABCD'
AND date in ('2013-04-04', '2013-04-03') limit 2;
```

I realized that the result of cassandra is ordered by the same sequence of patkeys in clausa IN. In this case, I'd like to know if the expected result is ALWAYS the two records of the day '2013-04-04'? Ie Cassadra respects the order of the IN clause in the ordering of the result even in a scenario with multiple nodes?

Comment: From what I can tell, "yes" it should respect the clustering order with multiple nodes.  Are you seeing something different?